# How to Change The custom keyboard color when pressed ...!

Tags: android, colors, background, keyboard

Hey I have Creating a game so I created custom keyboard(numPad) with edit-tex I can write a number once on the edit-text (number one appear once until I backspace it then i can write again ) so I want to change colors of the Keyboard I tried a code it changes the keys to blue when  pressing But I want to stay blue for example I pressed number (1234) this numbers on the keyboard change colors to blue and stay that way until I backspace this number it goes to his original color(unpressed color)
take a look of my code and pictures u will understand

[image: empty EditText]
[image: when I press number 1 want to stay blue util I backspace it]

MainActivty.java

```
    private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private EditText mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;
String textContainer = "";
int length = 0;
int prevLength = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);

    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);

    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                    this));



    mTargetView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            textContainer = s.toString();
            prevLength = s.length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            length = s.length();
                            if(!textContainer.isEmpty()){
                                if(s.length() > 1) {
                                    if(prevLength < length) {
                                        if (!textContainer.contains(s.toString().subSequence(length - 1, length))) {
                                            length = s.length();
                                        } else {
                            mTargetView.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                textContainer = s.toString();
            }


        }
    });

}


private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetActivity.this,
                        R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mKeyboardView.isShown()) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return    super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.example.mike.a12345.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"

    android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"


    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ></com.example.mike.a12345.CustomKeyboardView>
```

samplekeybackround.xml

```
    <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /></selector>
```

pressed.xml

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#A3D9F3" />
    <solid android:color="#4ABCE8"/>
   </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be with

```
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"/>
```